# Can RabbitMQ distribute tasks received from an exchange configuration?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Let's consider a standard `routing` configuration [as per documented on the RabbitMQ website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-php.html) defined with 2 routing keys `a` and `b` producing 2 associated queues.

I was wondering how to distribute the received messages among multiple workers with the `competing consumers pattern`: several workers consuming alternatively the messages received from `Qa` (same approach for `Qb`).
[image]

I tried to mix `routing` with `work queues` configurations but to no avail since messages are dispatched to all related workers instead of being alternatively distributed.

Is it only possible?

Comment: The messages should be distributed to workers instead of copied, maybe show some code how you're trying to do it? I'd also remove one of the queues to make it easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering how to distribute the received messages among multiple workers

each worker needs it's own queue, and each queue needs to receive a copy of the message

if you send Message.A through an exchange, you need to route Message.A to each of the queues for each worker that needs to process it. You can route a single message to as many queues as you want. The message will be duplicated into each queue.

Comment: I don't get it when you say "each worker needs its own queue". Implementing the `work queues` tutorial clearly shows that a single queue may have more than one consumer.

Comment: having multiple consumers on a single queue will load balance the message between the consumers. a single message in a single queue, will be handled by a single consumer. if multiple consumers need that message, each consumer  needs it's own queue with a copy of that message